# Image upload in retrofit : internal server error

Tags: android, image, file-upload, service, retrofit2

I am trying to upload a file to server but `responseObject.isSuccess()` is returning `false`. Below are the service and calling code. Please let me know what is wrong with the code.

API to post :

```
@Multipart
@POST("/operation/Api/fileSync")
Call<SyncResponse> uploadImage(
    @QueryMap Map<String, String> params, 
    @Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.jpg\" ") RequestBody image
);
```

and code to call service :

```
public void uploadImage() {

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClientManager
        .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
        .getRetrofitBuilder();
    SyncAPI syncAPI = retrofit.create(SyncAPI.class);

    MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
    File file = new File(KEY_NAME);
    RequestBody image = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file);

    Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    paramMap.put("AUTHCHECKSUM", authchecksum);
    paramMap.put("name",file.getName());
    paramMap.put("type","image/jpeg");


    Call<SyncResponse> call = syncAPI.uploadImage(paramMap, image);

    try {
        RetrofitClientManager
            .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .execute(1, call, this);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `TypedFile`:

```
import retrofit.mime.TypedFile;

@Multipart
@POST("/operation/Api/fileSync")
Call<SyncResponse> uploadImage(
    @QueryMap Map<String, String> params, 
    @Part("image") TypedFile image
)
```

then, in `uploadImage()` try the following:

```
File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
TypedFile typedImageFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", imageFile);
syncAPI.uploadImage(paramMap, typedImageFile);
```

Comment: i am using retrofit version 2 and TypedFile is not supported. i got another error. while posting by postman file is uploaded but not by code.